# Execute code after order has been confirmed in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, sales-order, order-status

Hi fellow programmers,

I would like to know how I can hook in to execute code after a certain action in Magento 2 has been done. As we're running a custom warehouse system, I'd like to reserve a customer's products after an order has been confirmed, but I have no clue as to how to do that.

I've looked in to overriding certain functions using plugins, but that seems a bit redundant as I don't want to copy the entire function body just to execute my own code afterwards.

I've read something about the special "after", "before" plugin functions you can specify, but I don't know how to implement those.

Is there another way or can I use the "before" and "after" plugin functions? If so, can someone point me towards a good resource that explains just that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [observer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) to run your codes after each action. And in your case, you can use `sales_order_save_after` to perform your task. Let's say, if you want to perform codes after order status changed to **Processing**, we can write the following codes:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $status = $order->getStatus();
    if ($status == "processing"){
        //do your codes
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I assume you know how to create an observer. If not, you can still refer to official documentation and refer to my codes above.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't implemented an observer yet ,but i'll find out how to do it!

Comment: If my method works, please accept my answer :)

Comment: Will do, i'm still looking how to make sure the observer is registered, please give me some time to figure it out :P

Answer (score 0):

To use events and observers in Magento 2, you need to do the following steps

•  Identify the event that you want to observe. For example, if you want to reserve a customer's products after an order has been confirmed, you can use the **sales_order_place_after** event

•  Create an observer class that implements the **Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface** interface and defines the execute method. This is where you write your custom code that will run when the event is triggered. For example, you can create a class called ReserveProducts in your custom module's Model folder

•  Declare your observer in the **events.xml** file in your custom module's etc folder. You need to specify the event name, the observer name, and the observer class. For example, you can create a file called **events.xml** in your custom module's **etc/frontend** folder and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_order_place_after">
     <observer name="reserve_products"
               instance="Vendor\Module\Model\ReserveProducts" />
   </event>
</config>
```

•  Clear the cache and test your observer.